# Fail to build node c++ addon

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, node.js-addon

I am working on a project that uses stereolab's depth camera [ZED](https://www.stereolabs.com/) to retrieve distance of obstacles. Its SDK is written in C++ and it requires CUDA 6.5. However, I have to integrate this program with another part of project, which is written in nodejs. So I decided to compile ZED code as a node module. I've gone through [node addon tutorial](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html). Now I've written the interface, but I got following error after trying to build the project using command "node-gyp configure build". **It seems the 'zed' module wasn't built.** I have no idea what this error is and I've searched nothing so far. Can someone please give me some directions? Thank you.

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@2.0.2
gyp info using node@0.12.7 | linux | x64
gyp info spawn python2
gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Path/to/My/Project/DepthViewer/node_zed_module/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/joe/.node-gyp/0.12.7/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/joe/.node-gyp/0.12.7',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Path/to/My/Project/DepthViewer/node_zed_module',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory `/Path/to/My/Project/DepthViewer/node_zed_module/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/zed/../src/main.o
/bin/sh: 1: -DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=zed: not found
make: [Release/obj.target/zed/../src/main.o] Error 127 (ignored)
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/zed.node
/bin/sh: 1: -shared: not found
make: [Release/obj.target/zed.node] Error 127 (ignored)
  COPY Release/zed.node
cp: cannot stat ‘Release/obj.target/zed.node’: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/zed.node] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/Path/to/My/Project/DepthViewer/node_zed_module/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-58-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /Path/to/My/Project/DepthViewer/node_zed_module
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

This is my binding.gyp:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "zed",
      "sources": [
        "../src/main.cpp",
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "/usr/local/zed/include/",
        "/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include/",
        "../include/"
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "zed_depth_viewer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Measure depth with zed sdk",
  "main": "zed_depth.js",
  "private": true,
  "gypfile": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bindings": "~1.2.1"
  }
}
```

And following is basically my interface with node: (just started for testing, 'initProgram' is working as 'main' for the project)

```
void node_main_handle(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope(isolate);

  Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = FunctionTemplate::New(isolate, initProgram);
  Local<Function> fn = tpl->GetFunction();

  // omit this to make it anonymous
  fn->SetName(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "initProgram"));

  args.GetReturnValue().Set(fn);
}

void Init(Handle<Object> exports, Handle<Object> module)
{
    NODE_SET_METHOD(module, "exports", node_main_handle);
}

NODE_MODULE(zed, Init)
```

An example using this module should be:

```
var zed = require('bindings')('zed'); //zed.node will be in './build/Release/'
var func = zed();
func();
```

Not sure if this works, haven't tested it yet. I'm new to nodejs.

Comment: Run `npm install --verbose` to see the complete log. It seems somehow that node cannot find the compile, instead of `bin/sh` you should have something line `/usr/bin/g++`.

Comment: Yeah, @Yan Foto you are right. It's my fault to export CXX='-std=c++11' (node told me this build needs the -std=c++11 flag for compilation), it should be export CXX='g++ -std=c++11'. I was mislead by another article I read previously. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the line `/bin/sh: 1: -DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=zed: not found` that the compiler cannot be found (it should be something like `/usr/bin/g++` instead of `/bin/sh`). If you want to have custom flags passed to gyp or if you want a specific compiler, your gyp file should like something like this:

```
{
  'make_global_settings': [
     ['CXX','/usr/bin/clang++-3.5'],
     ['LINK','/usr/bin/clang++-3.5'],
  ],
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "zed",
      "sources": [
        "../src/main.cpp",
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "/usr/local/zed/include/",
        "/usr/local/cuda-6.5/include/",
        "../include/"
      ],
      "link_settings": {
        "libraries": [ // For compiler
          "-requiredlibs",
        ],
        "ldflags": [  // For linker
            "-L</path/to/libs",
            "-Wl,-rpath,path/to/libs",
        ]
      },
      "cflags": [
        "-std=c++11"
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

The above gyp file uses `clang` (instead of `g++`) for compilation and linking and sets the correct `rpath` for the created shared library so you won't need to export the library path every time you want to use your binding!

For more information [this article](http://quaintous.com/2015/06/12/node-gyp-for-non-cpp-programmers/) might be useful!